# Emacs Word-Reordering Completion Style

Tags: emacs

I'm missing one piece in Emacs' already superbly unique *completion* system (`completion-styles` and `completion-styles-alist`), namely **word** and **sub-word-reordering** a la google search.

As an example, `file-write` should complete to `write-file` if no other style finds a completion. *Word*-separating characters could for-example be matched using the regular expression `"\\s_"`.

Even cooler and more general would be if applied the *[Damerau-Levenshtein](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance) Edit Distance* (`D`) to *words* instead of letters. The completion candidates could the be sorted on increasing distance `D`, meaning closest match first.

My plan is quite clear on how to implement this and an implementation of `D` already exists. I ask anyway so I don't reinvent the wheel yet another time:

Has anybody implemented such a completion style already?

Comment: You may also want to ask this on [emacs-devel](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.devel), because those guys know the most about emacs, so they will probably know if it's already implemented.

Comment: I think slime (common lisp development system) has a completion style like this.

Answer (score 1):

Per --

You cannot do what you want with vanilla Emacs (well, you can use Lisp to code whatever you need -- but you cannot do what you want not out of the box).

[***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) gives you exactly what you want.  It's called "**progressive completion**", and the idea is similar to using a pipeline of `grep` commands.

- [Nutshell view](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Nutshell_View#toc11) of progressive completion (and chipping away the non-elephant)
- [Progressive completion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Progressive_Completion)

You can also use [LevenShtein](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Fuzzy_Completion#toc9) matching for completion with **Icicles**, and combine that with progressive completion to match the words in any order.